# tensor dot operation in python

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I have two arrays `A=[1,2,3]` and `B=[[1],[0],[1],[0]]`. The question how to perform their tensor dot product in python. I am expecting to get:

```
C=[[1,2,3],
   [0,0,0],
   [1,2,3],
   [0,0,0]]
```

The function np.tensordot() returns an error concerning shapes of arrays.

A little addition to this question. How to do such operation if matrix are totally different in shape, like:

```
A=[[1,1,1,1],
   [1,1,1,1],
   [2,2,2,2],
   [3,3,3,3]]

B=[2,1]

C=[[[2,1],[2,1],[2,1],[2,1]],
   [[2,1],[2,1],[2,1],[2,1]],
   [[4,2],[4,2],[4,2],[4,2]],
   [[6,3],[6,3],[6,3],[6,3]]]
```

Comment: Concerning the addition:  I have no clue what the result of a dot multiplication of these should be.  Maybe if you give a more detailed explanation on how you want it to be computed, we could figure out ways to make `numpy` do it for you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using correct `numpy` arrays:

```
>>> array([[1],[2],[3]]).dot(array([[1,0,1,0]]))
array([[1, 0, 1, 0],
       [2, 0, 2, 0],
       [3, 0, 3, 0]])
```

If your alignment is different, using `a.transpose()` can flip it:

```
>>> array([[1],[2],[3]]).dot(array([[1,0,1,0]])).transpose()
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

If you (for whatever reason) have to use `tensordot()`, try this:

```
>>> numpy.tensordot([1,2,3], [1,0,1,0], axes=0)
array([[1, 0, 1, 0],
       [2, 0, 2, 0],
       [3, 0, 3, 0]])
```

Comment: This comes a bit late but...  Is it fastest to use `dot` than `tensordot`? for all practical purposes do they output the same result?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not so expert with this argument but if you try to change axes in numpy it works:

```
A=[1,2,3]
B=[[1],[0],[1],[0]]
np.tensordot(B, A, axes=0)
array([[[1, 2, 3]],

   [[0, 0, 0]],

   [[1, 2, 3]],

   [[0, 0, 0]]])
```