# How to generate a usable tensor product of two matrices in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296028/tensor-dot-operation-in-python) successfully answers how to use numpy to calculate the tensor product of two matrices in Python.  However, I want the output to be in a proper matrix format so that further calculations can be performed on it without my manually editing it.

For instance,

```
I=matrix([[1,0],[0,1]])
print np.tensordot(I, I, axes=0)
```

Gives the output:

```
[[[[1 0]
   [0 1]]

  [[0 0]
   [0 0]]]


 [[[0 0]
   [0 0]]

  [[1 0]
   [0 1]]]]
```

I want it in the form:

```
[[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]]
```

so that I can perform further operations on it within the program itself.

How do I do this?

Comment: The Kronecker tensor product can be calculated using [numpy.kron](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html), if that is what you are searching for. If it isn't, could you give a definition of the product you're after?

Comment: @Phillip it seems you found the solution, you could post your comment as an answer...

Comment: Oh, perfect! This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much. I was hoping the answer was a simple one that I may have overlooked.

Comment: Good to hear. I've reposted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

The Kronecker tensor product can be calculated using [numpy.kron](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html).